# Share Firefox/Thunderbird data between W7 and Linux Mint 12 in dual boot computer

Tags: windows-7, linux-mint

I've just set up my laptop (where I had running only W7) with a dual boot to run Linux Mint 12 as well.

I have a "Data" partition (apart from the required partitions for W7 and Linux) where I store pretty much everything that isn't software installations (music, videos, project files, etc).

I seem to be able to access that NTFS partition totally fine from Mint (like I've always done with W7), which is cool because I can access all that stuff regardless of which OS I'm using.

I would like to know if it's possible (and how) to go one step further and share programs data between the two OS. One example would be my Firefox and Thunderbird data. For example, in Firefox share my bookmarks (and if I could share history, autocomplete and all that stuff, that would be awesome). In thunderbird, be able to share my mail and configuration, seeing the same inbox, folders, message rules, etc... So if I receive/send an email from W7 and later switch to Mint, I can see that email as it had been received/sent from Mint, and vice versa.

Is this even possible? Or am I asking for too much convenience? If it's possible, any clues on how to set it all up?

Comment: While Linux can read a Fat32/NTFS partition Windows and Linux use different encodings.  What you want is unlikely to be possible for that reason alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows, usually the application data is in something such as:

```
"C:Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\".
```

In Linux, it should be in:

```
 "/home/username/.mozilla/firefox".
```

Now since Linux can view Fat32/NTFS partitions, it would probably be best to have your Linux partition read from the Windows partition to share the data, however you would need to make sure that drive is mounted all the time.

Now you have to make sure the Linux firefox reads from the same profile:

```
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_:_FAQs_:_Changing_Profile_Folder_Location
```

I believe this should work as long as they read from the same place and use the same data, they are in sync. Also, you should be able to for this for Thunderbird as well. I have moved my profile data to an encrypted partition before, this should not be too much different.

Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: thanks for your advice! I'll give this a try and see if it works. Do you know how can I make sure that the drive is mounted all the time? Is there a setting for that?

Comment: Well I use Ubuntu, I've never tried to Mint, however they should be similar. But when I put my FireFox profile in a new drive, it was an encrypted TrueCrypt which I mounted manually every time I booted my PC. Maybe you could have script that mounts the drive or simply just mount it before you run FireFox.

Comment: I've been checking the link you provided but I can't find the way to tell firefox where it should look for an existing profile. I can see how to create a new one, and how to move an existing one, but I can't find the option to tell firefox to load the profile info from an existing one...

Comment: Yes! You got it, command should be "firefox -profilemanager", then you create a new user and select the folder. Next, you can import everything else to that new user.

Comment: thank you for your help! I managed to make it work for both using the Profile Manager. However, I got this error in Linux after a while. I closed Firefox and when opening it again, it asked to choose the profile (I had created a new one instead of overwriting the default one). I chose the profile, I got an error saying that the profile was being used, but no other Firefox window was open, so I don't know what happened... any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: This sounds like when you close Firefox in Linux too fast and then try to re-open it again as the process is still closing. I've had similar issues, however, maybe you can only use one profile. Try killing the process first.

Comment: nope, it's happening also with Thunderbird (in this case it's not even asking for the profile, it just says that the program itself is already open but not responding). The weird thing is that I had even restarted my laptop...

Comment: When I have not mounted my TrueCrypt drive(that has all my profiles for ThunderBird and Firefox), I get the same error. Are you loading ThunderBird and Firefox on your Linux partition?

Comment: you' are right! That was my problem, I had not mounted the partition. It seems to work fine now, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Comment: I tried to auto mount that partition using the Storage Device Manager app, but it didn't work, and messed up the fstab file. I have a backup that SDM created (fstab.bak), do you know how can I restore that backup? I can't figure out how to do that...

Comment: Ah, I am not sure, I only have my TrueCrypt file in which I mount then everything works because of the directories I set. Sorry :(

Comment: ok, no worries, I'll try to figure it out. Thanks!